# In-/upserting a nested document in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to upsert a nested document (activities) in a structure similar to

```
{
  "_id" : "123",
  "modules" : {
    "x" : {
    },
    "y" : {
      "activities" : {
        "preview": {
          "createdAt": "2014-10-13 15:21:22.113",
          "data": {}
        }
      }
    },
    "z" : {
      "activities" : {
        "render": {
          "createdAt": "2014-10-15 04:22:25.171",
          "data": {}
        },
        "render": {
          "createdAt": "2014-10-14 02:42:24.132",
          "data": {}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I then try

```
selector = { "_id": id, "modules": module, "activities" }
activity = { "preview": { "data": data }}
Meteor.users.upsert(selector, { $set: activity, $setOnInsert: { "createdAt: new Date()" }})
```

Which yields

```
MongoError: insertDocument :: caused by :: 11000 E11000 duplicate key error index: meteor.users.$_id_  dup key: { : "123" }
```

`_id` is a unique index key. There are additional fields/documents on the `_id` 'level' of each user and on the `activities` 'level' of each module, but none concerning the upsert. Each module is unique. The activities document doesn't exist before the first record is inserted.

With that, I hope someone gets the gist of what I'm trying to accomplish and can help me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upsert is for insert or update(if exist) a new document. It does not apply for a sub-document.

You should just update your document:

```
selector = { "_id": id, "modules": module, preview : null }
activity = { "preview": { "data": data , "createdAt" : new Date() }}
Meteor.users.update(selector, { $set: 'activity' : activity }})
```

Comment: Not sure I follow. I would want to upsert the subdocument if it exists (while not updating it's createdAt).

Comment: answer updated. you cannot use upsert for sub-document. you should check if preview doesn't exist then an a add new field name preview with update command ;)